# Trace routes to find the downtime reason

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Our server was down for serving http requests for some minutes. The web server is nginx and php-fpm handles the php processes. So in the middle of downtime duration I took a look at nginx's `access.log` file. Most of requests were getting a 499 response code which is nginx particular status code for when client closes the connection before the server answers.

I restarted nginx `sudo nginx -s reload` but that didn't seem to effect the behavior. I then restarted `php-fpm` service and everything came back normal. Before issuing service restart, `htop` was showing no high CPU usage.

My question is how can I find the reason in such situations and where should I start from to get to the bottleneck?

Comment: Are you using a Load Balancer in front of your Nginx? If yes, you can try increase the timeout of the LB.

Comment: Please, could you make your introduction more clear: `your server was down` did you mean baremetal, or whole service (nginx+php-fpm)? Are you looking for the reason of failing to serve http requests, or the reason of those amount of 499?

Comment: @MassiveGRID No there is no load balancer.

Comment: @VictorPerov If by *bare-metal* you mean something like power outage, no I was able to ssh to server. I think I cleared *server was down* by saying *for serving http requests*. So yes better to say web server was down. And to answer your second question I think both because they are probably related.